# iOS load new storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard

Simple iOS App with a storyboard - StoryboardA

When the iPad changes orientation - I would like to load a new storyboard - StoryboardB

Where do I put that logic.

Is this a good practice when the UI in landscape (and it's navigation) is different than in portrait.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice when rotating the screen is to relayout the views. This is the whole reason behind the autoresizing (springs and struts) that has been around for a while, as well as the new autolayout functionality. You're supposed to be able to use this to reorganize your views as necessary when rotating, and you should ideally see a smooth rotation as a result. It's discouraged to destroy and recreate resources such as UI elements upon rotation, unlike in the Android world where that's actually the preferred and default method.

Generally if the UI is actually different in some way between portrait and landscape, it still has much in common, so there might be an additional section that appears in landscape, for example, which gets hidden in portrait. I would recommend against radically changing your UI upon rotation, because this is definitely not the norm and would be jarring to users. You can easily hide or show an additional section when rotating without much hassle.

If you must recreate your views upon rotation instead of rearranging them, you can at least still keep them in the same storyboard. It isn't necessary to use a whole new storyboard just for this purpose.

As for where you would put your logic for handling this, if you did decide to go with this approach, it would depend on what exactly needs to change upon rotation. If every view controller needs to be recreated, you may have the logic to handle this in your app delegate. But if it's just specific view controllers, you might put the logic to detect and handle these cases only in those specific controllers.

As I said, I highly discourage this approach, and I think it would be much better to use the mechanisms that already exist to relayout your views upon rotation.

Comment: My storyboard has a simple UIViewController.  All controls for this UIViewcontroller are arranged at design time for a portrait layout.  In landscape the controls remain the same but will not work with autoresizing so they need to be placed manually and resized.

Given that I am using a storyboard and not a xib file - do I create a new view controller for landscape.

Comment: Okay, so in your UIViewController subclass, simply rearrange these upon rotation. There's no need to destroy and recreate it, and could be problematic. If you already created another view controller in another storyboard with your ideal landscape layout, you can at least get the values that all of your elements should be moved to from that, and put it in your code to reorganize them.

Comment: You are proposing to do it programatically. I would like to do them them at design time.  

Would like to hear why programmatically is better than design.

Comment: Because your approach involves destroying and recreating the resources, which is not a preferred way on iOS. If you would like to do this, though, a possible solution might be to have two separate views in the same view controller, one of which is the portrait content and the other the landscape content. Then you can hide one and show the other upon rotation. Doing this, you just have to keep the two in sync with each other, so that one reflects changes made in the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can register for UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification in following way

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                             selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                             object:nil];
```

and on being notified of above mentioned UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, your orientationChanged: method will get fired, in which you can implement whatever layout changes you want to implement as follows:-

Create a BOOL flag in your private interface, isShowingLandscapeView, to keep track of which orientation currently device is on and act accordingly

```
BOOL isShowingLandscapeView = NO;

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) &&
        !isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        // Changes pertaining to lanscape orientation here
        isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
    }
    else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation) &&
         isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        // Changes pertaining to portrait orientation here
        isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: My question is not how to detect if the orientation is changed.  

When the orientation has changed - I want to bring in a view that has been created at design time.  Currently this view is in a storyboard. 
Question is where to I design my second view.  I don't want to move everything programmatically as @Gavin seems to suggest.  I want to have a view that is laid out at design time and then just bring it in when rotation happens.

Comment: Sorry for misinterpreting your question.

Comment: You can create storyboard for different orientation and load them accordingly else if your app's deployment target is iOS 6 and larger, you can take advantage of AutoLayout feature which appeared to be a better way of designing layout for different orientations.

Comment: [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@”Your storyboard” bundle:nil]

Answer (score 0):

You can load other storyboard in following way.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"your storyboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *initialViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:initialViewController animated:YES];
```