# How to add a project inside a xcode project as a module

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am already having an  APP with some modules.Now i want to add another project to it as a module.

On a button click  of first project i want to run the second project.Like i want to load storyboard of second project from the first one.is there any way to do so.

Comment: Yes. You'll have to add a new target application. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23192693/add-a-second-target-in-the-xcode-5-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by loading a the other storyboard on your project.

see this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20912863/2164705), as it might be able to answer your question.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/StoryboardScene.html) you can have the Documentation from Apple Developers Site